# Ant multi module projects to maven

Tags: java, maven, ant, pom.xml, build.xml

The ant project has different modules, which produce multiple jars. Some of the submodules produce again multiple jars. The requirement is to convert it to a maven project and get rid of ant.
I have seen some suggestions to maven a multi-project or use profiles in pom.xml to create multiple jars.

[image: Ant project structure]

Above is the folder structure for my ant project. What is the best way to convert it to a maven project? Convert big modules to the stand-alone project and small modules to a maven multi-project?

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: First step. Migrate to the correct directory structure `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/test/java` and `src/test/resources`... Second why does a single module produce several jar's? What is the differenct? presumably based on packages? What do you mean by "a lot of subfolders"? Do you mean java packages?

Comment: yes, java packages. It's a legacy ant project (Please see the project structure in the attached image).

Comment: So you should separate the packages into separate Ant modules and afterwards migrate to modules... because rule of thumb one module one jar...

Comment: Some modules have only a few classes (3-8), can't we make it a multi-module maven project, which will generate jars separately right?

Comment: It does not really matter if a module has only a few classes ... make it separate it's easier... than fiddle the configuration to create more than one jar from a single module...

Comment: Thanks, your comments are valuable :)